# Android: get process ID that created folder

Tags: android, pid, ls

Is there some way how to obtain PID of process that created some folder? By ls -l, I get UID and GID only. I am quite sure that it was possible but I forgot how I did it last time. And I am not able to find it.

In more details: I am sure that I was able to pair folder in with app that created it. And I used PID obtained by `android.os.Process.myUid()` for pairing. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Android is a Linux system, and Linux is Unix-like.  Unix filesystems store the user and group that own it.  Process ids are temporal, and don't have any long-term meaning.  They are not stored in the filesystem.

Comment: My fault, it was really UID not PID